# How to query (fetch) a multiple table of mysql database as a single table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, codeigniter

I have three database table

**1st**

```
vedd_plan_task ::
task_id | task name
```

**2nd**

```
  plan_task_mapping ::
  task_mapp_id | plan_id | task_id
```

**3rd**

```
tbl_plan ::
plan_id | plan_title | plan_price | plan_desc
```

In this table i mapped the 2nd table with 1st & 3rd. (2 table's value come from 1st & 3rd)

for **PLAN** i call the data from **PLAN TASK** tbl. and submit the data in two different table. 
now i have to show the database as table but i can't find the way to get a task_name form mapping table.

I want a table with this field

Plan_id | plan_title | plan_price | plan_desc | task_name (which i inserted before with particular plan id)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT tbl_plan.plan_id ,plan_title ,plan_price ,plan_desc ,task_name,plan_task_mapping.task_id FROM tbl_plan LEFT JOIN plan_task_mapping ON plan_task_mapping.plan_id = tbl_plan.plan_id LEFT JOIN vedd_plan_task ON vedd_plan_task.task_id = plan_task_mapping.task_id');

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {    

echo $row->plan_id; 
echo $row->plan_title;
echo $row->plan_price;
echo $row->plan_desc;
echo $row->task_name; 
echo $row->task_id; 

} ?>
```

Comment: i get other values...  except still can't get task_id and plan_id .. and it shows : Undefined property: stdClass::$plan_id
Undefined property: stdClass::$task_id

Comment: check now.just edited plan_id and added task_id in query.

Comment: sir thanks...  sir 1 more question... i got 4 entry as for single plan i have to show like single plan has multiple  task ...  hope u understand

Comment: you have  to use **order by** like **order by plan_id DESC LIMIT 1**.Thanks

Comment: Sorry i am unable 2 understand your above sentence ** i got 4 entry as for single plan i have to show like single plan has multiple task**

Comment: sorry sir didn't get you ...  actually i have to fetch data form tbl_plan and the mapping table but the mapping data comes form task table so i have to show the data from plan table as plan data and as with the selected task only ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->join('vedd_plan_task','vedd_plan_task.task_id=plan_task_mapping.task_id','inner');
$this->db->join('plan_task_mapping ','plan_task_mapping.plan_id=tbl_plan.plan_id ','inner');
$this->db->get('tbl_plan');
```

Comment: Use this code i have connect all table and fetch all data check code and send me

Comment: still got  error of ::: Unknown column 'plan_task_mapping.task_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); check query

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('tbl_plan.plan_id,tbl_plan.plan_title,tbl_plan.plan_price,tbl_plan.plan_price,tbl_plan.plan_desc,vedd_plan_task.task_name');

$this->db->from('plan_task_mapping,tbl_plan,vedd_plan_task');

$this->db->where('plan_task_mapping.plan_id = tbl_plan.plan_id and plan_task_mapping.task_id=vedd_plan_task.task_id');

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```