# after fetching a database table now i have to edit it in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, left-join

I have this three database table

> **vedd_plan_task**
>
> -task_id,
>   -task_name,
>
> **tbl_plan**
>
> -plan_id,
>   -plan_title,
>   -plan_price,
>   -plan_desc,
>
> **plan_task_mapping**
>
> -task_mapp_id,
>   -plan_id,
>   -task_id,

The Flow of process is like --
i am creating a edit/update/delete system of this data.
i create a form to insert plan data,i fetch the task name dynamically on that page and the insert the data in to database with mapping technique.
means while inserting i mapped the Plan_id and Task_id in mapping table.

I successfully inserted it. and display in my view table. now i have to edit this detail. but first i have to show this detail in my view (like plan detail in input box as plan the selected task in check box)

Now i have to fetch this data  for edit them ...   i can't fetch the proper way as.. Means can't get proper task_name as plan_id. Help me please...

> "plan_title | plan_price | plan_desc | task_name "

This is the plan Model

```
public function getPlanById($planId)
{
    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_plan');
    return $query->result();    
}

public function getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId)
{      
    $this->db->where('plan_id', $planId);
    $query = $this->db->get('plan_task_mapping');
    return $query->result();   
}

function getAllVeddingTask()
{   
    $query = $this->db->get('vedd_plan_task');
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is the controller

```
public function editPlanData($planId)
{
    $data['veddingPlanData'] = $this->PlanModel->getPlanById($planId);
    $data['veddingPlanTaskMappingData'] = $this->PlanModel->getPlanAndTaskMappingByPlanId($planId);
    $data['allVedingTasks'] = $this->VeddingTaskModel->getAllVeddingTask();
    $this->load->view('plan_update', $data);
}
```

I dump data successfully...  in my view now i have to show only that task which is selected for plan..  means the i have to show task_name as plan_id. threw mapping tale

```
<?php  var_dump($veddingPlanData);  ?>
<?php  var_dump($veddingPlanTaskMappingData);  ?>
<?php  var_dump($allVedingTasks);  ?>
```

this is my view

now help me to fetch that plan with the specific task_name as check box and plan data in input box..  hear in view i comment the dump part ..  i dump it successfully. so i just want to edit that data which is called on product id..  as product id the data come from mapping and then the task_name came form task table.

Comment: Read up on SQL joins, try something and then show your code

Comment: This should help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: don't cut my reputation....  i ask a question  ...   and before asking it i try it...  sir...  now i edit it !!   give me solution of it .. @MikeMiller

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query (fetch) a multiple table of mysql database as a single table in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427631/how-to-query-fetch-a-multiple-table-of-mysql-database-as-a-single-table-in-cod)

Comment: sir... that question for fetch that data...  now i have to edit this data...  for edit this i have to call it threw plan_id and show the task_name which i select for particular plan_id.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Still seems like you need relationships in your sql

Comment: You could look at Grocery_CRUD

Comment: no sir... I am working on INSERT/SHOW/EDIT/UPDATE/DELETE of plan data..  i while inserting the Each Plan have it's Task_Name and the task name come form Task Table.. threw Mapping task_id in Mapping table. 
i successfully inserted it..  show it in table and now i have to create a edit the data by creating edit view for it. show when i click on EDIT of that database table it goes to update page and show the data of that particular plan_id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked this question many years ago when I have started the Codeigniter. 
So I am posting the answer to my own question.

In this question, I needed to get data using join for edit `vedding_task` according to `vedding_task`.

So here is the JOIN query.

```
$prop_master_table = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('plan_task_mapping as ptm')
    ->join('vedd_plan_task as vpt', 'ptm.task_id = vpt.task_id', 'left outer')
    ->join('tbl_plan as tp', 'ptm.plan_id = tp.plan_id', 'left outer')                
    ->where('vpt.task_id', $task_id)
    ->where('tp.plan_id', $plan_id)
    ->get();
```